# MapReduce reducer wrong output

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a large TSV file with following input:

```
Site1 Tag1
Site1 Tag34
Site1 Tag8
Site2 Tag75
Site2 Tag54
Site2 Tag8
Site3 Tag24
Site3 Tag34
Site3 Tag1
...
```

I want to find, with help of hadoop MapReduce, similar site pairs between all sites in input and number of similar tags in them per each pair.

Output for partial input presented:

```
Site1 Site2 1  // Site1 is similar to Site2 with 1 tag (Tag8)
Site1 Site3 2  // Site1 is similar to Site3 with 2 tag (Tag1 and Tag34)
Site2 Site1 1
Site3 Site1 2
```

I want to output only 10 most similar sites per each site.

Each site have 3 tags

I thought to use 2 MapReduce jobs:

1. To map tag(key) and site and reduce by tag, in reduce phase to take all sites for specific tag and to write output 'tag SiteX SiteY'
2. Second MapReduce job will take the first input and will perform GROUP BY SiteX,SiteY pair to get number of similar tags in pair of similar sites.

I tried to implement the first MAPRED but what I get are just "tag,site" output.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class RawToSimilarTagMapper {

    public static class TagToSiteMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {

        private Text    site    = new Text();
        private Text    tag     = new Text();

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String [] siteTag = value.toString().split("\t");
            site.set(siteTag[0]);
            tag.set(siteTag[1]);

            context.write(tag, site);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static class SimilarSiteReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
        private Text value = new Text();

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            for (Text text : values) {
                for (Text text2 : values) {
                    if (!text.equals(text2)) {
                        value.set(text.toString() + "\t" + text2.toString());
                        output.collect(key, value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "raw-to-similar");
        job.setJarByClass(RawToSimilarTagMapper.class);
        job.setMapperClass(TagToSiteMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(SimilarSiteReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(SimilarSiteReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));
        FileSystem fs = null;
        Path dstFilePath = new Path(args[2]);
        try {
            fs = dstFilePath.getFileSystem(conf);
            if (fs.exists(dstFilePath))
                fs.delete(dstFilePath, true);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong here ?

Also for the next stage how can I get only the top 10 most similar sites per each site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it. Further you can do sorting to get top ten sites by writing third job on second job's output.(Hint: You will only need to write mapper) NOTE: This works on sample data provided in question. you may need to do initial clean up for bad formatted data.

Final output:

```
Site2   2
Site2   Site1   1
Site3   1
Site3   Site1   2
```

Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.MultipleInputs;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;

public class TopSites{

    public static class TagToSiteMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String [] siteTag = value.toString().split("\t");
            context.write(new Text(siteTag[1]), new Text(siteTag[0]));
            System.out.println(siteTag[1] + " --> " + siteTag[0]);
        }
    }


    public static class TagToSiteReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String l =  "";
            System.out.print("Key: [" + key.toString() + "] Values: [");

            for (Text site : values)
                l += site + "\t";

            l=l.substring(0, l.length()-1);
            System.out.println(l + "]");
            context.write(new Text(key), new Text(l));
        }
    }
    public static class TopSiteMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            String [] data = value.toString().split("\t");
            String sites ="";
            System.out.println("map received: "+ value.toString());

            for(int i=1;i<data.length;i++)
                sites += data[i] + "\t";    

            System.out.println(sites.substring(0,sites.length()-1));
            context.write(new Text(sites.substring(0,sites.length()-1)), one);
        }
    }

    public static class TopSiteReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum =  0;
            System.out.print("Key: [" + key.toString() + "] Values: [");

            for (IntWritable site : values){
                System.out.print(site.get());
                sum+=site.get();
            }
            System.out.println("]");
            context.write(new Text(key), new IntWritable(sum));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        Job job  = Job.getInstance(conf, "site-to-tag");

        job.setJarByClass(TopSites.class);
        job.setMapperClass(TagToSiteMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(TagToSiteReducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job,  new Path(args[0]),TextInputFormat.class, TagToSiteMapper.class);

        Path outputpath = new Path(args[1]+"_temp");
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,outputpath);

        FileSystem fs = null;
        Path dstFilePath = new Path(args[1]);
        try {
            fs = dstFilePath.getFileSystem(conf);
            if (fs.exists(dstFilePath))
                fs.delete(dstFilePath, true);

            dstFilePath = new Path(args[1]+"_temp");
            fs = dstFilePath.getFileSystem(conf);
            if (fs.exists(dstFilePath))
                fs.delete(dstFilePath, true);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        int code = job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1;
        if(code == 0)
        {
            Job SecondJob = Job.getInstance(conf, "Tag-to-Sites");
            SecondJob.setJarByClass(TopSites.class);

            SecondJob.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            SecondJob.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

            SecondJob.setMapperClass(TopSiteMapper.class);
            SecondJob.setCombinerClass(TopSiteReducer.class);
            SecondJob.setReducerClass(TopSiteReducer.class);


            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(SecondJob,new Path(args[1]+ "_temp"));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(SecondJob,new Path(args[1]));
            int exitCode = SecondJob.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1;
            FileSystem.get(conf).delete(new Path(args[1]+"_temp"), true);
            System.exit(exitCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Console std output:

```
Tag1 --> Site1
Tag34 --> Site1
Tag8 --> Site1
Tag75 --> Site2
Tag54 --> Site2
Tag8 --> Site2
Tag24 --> Site3
Tag34 --> Site3
Tag1 --> Site3
Key: [Tag1] Values: [Site3  Site1]
Key: [Tag24] Values: [Site3]
Key: [Tag34] Values: [Site3 Site1]
Key: [Tag54] Values: [Site2]
Key: [Tag75] Values: [Site2]
Key: [Tag8] Values: [Site2  Site1]
map received: Tag1  Site3   Site1
Site3   Site1
map received: Tag24 Site3
Site3
map received: Tag34 Site3   Site1
Site3   Site1
map received: Tag54 Site2
Site2
map received: Tag75 Site2
Site2
map received: Tag8  Site2   Site1
Site2   Site1
Key: [Site2] Values: [11]
Key: [Site2 Site1] Values: [1]
Key: [Site3] Values: [1]
Key: [Site3 Site1] Values: [11]
Key: [Site2] Values: [2]
Key: [Site2 Site1] Values: [1]
Key: [Site3] Values: [1]
Key: [Site3 Site1] Values: [2]
```

Comment: For 2nd/3rd job you can also use pig script

Answer (score 0):

Looks your combiner is posing a problem here. The output format of mapper & combiner must be same which is not true in your case. Can you comment out combiner as its used for performance optimization only and run the same.